# C++ Multi dimensional array from external file question

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to get a contiguous line with values separated by "&" to load into a multi-dimensional array.  Here's the way I'm trying to do it - Everything checks out in the code, except the string "str" which contains my separated values in the format "value1, value2, value3, etc..." just loads that whole string into array[0][0].  I know there are better ways of doing this, but what I would like to know is why C++ won't treat "str" as if I had typed out the individual values and hard coded "array".

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    string str, strTotal;

    ifstream in;

    in.open("Desktop/01_001.PAC");

    getline(in,str);
    while ( in ) {
        strTotal += str;
        getline(in,str);
    }


    string searchString( "&" ); 
    string replaceString( ", " );

    assert( searchString != replaceString );

    string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ( (pos = str.find(searchString, pos)) != string::npos ) {
        str.replace( pos, searchString.size(), replaceString );
        pos++;
    }



    string array[4][5] = {str};

    cout << array[0][0];

    return(0);
}
```

And here is the external file (`"Desktop/01_001.PAC"`):

```
void&void&void&void&a&a1&a2&a3&b&b1&b2&b3&c&c1&c2&c3&d&d1&d2&d3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're just learning to program (which it sounds like you are) then C++ is honestly about the worst possible language you could really be starting with.

Comment: I have programmed mostly in web languages like PHP, Javascript, etc. and just started C++ yesterday.  I'm trying to apply PHP ideas to C++ and it has been a living hell, haha...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because code and data are different things. Your code is compiled before it runs.

It sounds as if this is what you expect:

1. The string contains the text "foo, bar, baz".
2. The statement `string[] whatever = {str};` is run.
3. Since "str" contains "foo, bar, baz", you want it to have the same effect **as if the line of code were actually** `string[] whatever = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}`.

Asking something like this implies a complete misunderstanding of how programming works.

Nothing this magical will ever happen in C++. It **cannot**, because (a) what if you actually wanted to put 'str' into the array? (b) what if 'foo', 'bar' and 'baz' were also variables in your program - should they be interpreted the same way?

**Variable names are not text. They no longer exist, for all practical purposes, at the time that your code runs**. They are only there so that you, as the programmer, can say "the value that is used over *here* should be the same one that is used over *there*".

Further, array initializations in C++ **do not care how many elements are actually in the initialization vs. the declared size of the array**. Any additional elements will be default-initialized (i.e., assigned empty strings).

A string **cannot be treated like an array of strings, because it isn't one**. If you want an array of strings, then build it, using the individual string elements as you determine them.

But since you don't know in advance how many elements there are, you should use `std::vector` instead of an array. And why are you trying to arrange the data into a 2-dimensional structure? How are you expecting to know how "wide" it should be?

Comment: I understand that variable names are not text.  I am trying to declare string array[4][5] using an external file.  If I were to set it up and hard code the values, I would put "string array[4][5] = {void, void, void, void, a1, a2, etc...};"  Also...  I know about vectors, I just was curious as to why I can't substitute a variable's values into the string array declaration.

Comment: First off, no you wouldn't put that, because 'void' doesn't work that way. Second, no you wouldn't put that, becuase for example "a2" is a string and not a variable name. Third, the answer is pretty much dedicated to explaining why you can't do that: because there is no reason why you could reasonably expect it to work. It simply doesn't make any sense. The closest thing, in terms of semantics, that you could do is read all twenty strings into separate variables, and then use those in the initialization statement, but that is unbelievably messy.

Comment: void was just a sample value, not a function... sorry for the confusion.  I suppose my issue here is that I thought declaring string array and int array would work the same way only with multiple characters vs numerical values... Turns out, I got a whole string of compile errors.  Anyhow...  My question still remains, why can't I substitute the hard code values for an array declaration with a variable containing that same string of code?  ie: replace "int array[4][5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc...};" with "int array[4][5] = {variable1};"  and have 'string variable1 = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc..";' above?

Comment: Because they aren't the same type. The array is an array of strings. It holds multiple strings. Each element is a string. The variable is a string. It holds a string. Therefore, it can represent an element, but it can't represent "the entire contents of the array". A string is not the same kind of thing as an array of strings. What you're asking is analogous to: "I have this book-shelf, and I have a book with this fancy dust-cover that's decorated to look like it has a bunch of books on it. Why can't I fill my book-shelf with the books drawn on the dust-cover, side by side?"

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you appear to be searching through the string (loaded from file), and only assigning the very last result to an array index (x=4, y=5). So your code is doing something like this:

```
while (have not found last variable)
    search for next variable in string

assign variable to (4,5) in matrix
```

So that last assignment might even work, but since you only assign at the end, the array is not going to be filled the way I think you want it to be filled.

I'm going to assume the matrix you want is always the same size, otherwise things get more complicated. In this case, you could use something like this:

```
let xMax = 4
let yMax = 5

for (x from 0 to xMax)
    for (y from 0 to yMax)
        find the next variable in the string
        assign it to the current (x,y) location in matrix
```

Debug statements are your friend here! Try the above solution without saving it to an array, and instead print out each term, to see if it is working correctly.

I would also point out that the string "void" is not the C++ keyword void, and so will not work if you want an array index to be void. Try getting your code to work without voids at first.

Comment: That section you are talking about first with the "while" statement simply replaces the "&" from the source string with ", ".  What I'm trying to accomplish here is the equivalent of declaring - "string array[4][5] = {void, void, void, void, a1, a2, etc...}" using an external source.

Comment: BTW: I was putting "Void" in the text file simply for a sample value, I had no intention of using a C++ keyword.